# How do I make a path out of a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-3.2, hashmap

I am trying to locate the route of the shortest path of a map(connected nodes with weight/distance).

Let's assume I have a hash like this:

```
{"A"=>{"B"=>1, "E"=>1}, "B"=>{"A"=>1, "C"=>1, "F"=>1}, "C"=>{"B"=>1, "D"=>1, "G"=>1}, "D"=>{"C"=>1, "H"=>1}, "E"=>{"F"=>1, "A"=>1, "I"=>1}, "F"=>{"E"=>1, "G"=>1, "B"=>1, "J"=>1}, "G"=>{"F"=>1, "H"=>1, "C"=>1, "K"=>1}, "H"=>{"G"=>1, "D"=>1, "L"=>1}, "I"=>{"J"=>1, "E"=>1, "M"=>1}, "J"=>{"I"=>1, "K"=>1, "F"=>1, "N"=>1}, "K"=>{"J"=>1, "L"=>1, "G"=>1, "O"=>1}, "L"=>{"K"=>1, "H"=>1, "P"=>1}, "M"=>{"N"=>1, "I"=>1}, "N"=>{"M"=>1, "O"=>1, "J"=>1}, "O"=>{"N"=>1, "P"=>1, "K"=>1}, "P"=>{"O"=>1, "L"=>1}}
```

Now I want to traverse and make a path from this hash. For example:

From Source A to Destination: L

Output should be: either `A -> E -> I -> J -> K -> L` or `A -> B -> C -> D -> H -> L`.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
def find_path(src, dst, init = [])
  path = [src]
  neighbors = self.neighbors(src)
  puts "src: #{src}"
  puts "dst: #{dst}"
  # puts "node: #{node}"
  puts "init: #{init}"
  puts "path: #{path}"
  puts "----\n"

  if neighbors.include?(dst)
    path.push(dst)
  else
    path.push(@nodes[src].keys.map{|k| k unless init.flatten.include? k }.reject(&:blank?).each{|key| self.find_path(key, dst, init << path) } )
  end
  return path
end
```

But, this prints only :  ["A", ["B", "E"]]

Which is not the desired output, can anybody tell me how do I go make this work? Thanks.

**Update:** This was used for locating the route of the shortest path of a map(connected nodes with weight/distance). Here are the details on what I was trying to achieve in this question: https://gist.github.com/suryart/6439102

Comment: Could you explain your algorithm, please?

Comment: can you explain how you get to the desired answer? what the hash is for? and what do the numbers mean (if they mean anything since all the numbers are 1)?

Comment: Numbers don't mean anything for the answer I was looking for. They are the distance/ weight between two nodes. I wanted to traverse through the path which connects these nodes. The answer below is the exact solution I was looking for. I'll update the question in an hour with the reference to gist containing all the details. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original hash:

```
h = {"A"=>{"B"=>1, "E"=>1}, "B"=>{"A"=>1, "C"=>1, "F"=>1}, "C"=>{"B"=>1, "D"=>1, "G"=>1}, "D"=>{"C"=>1, "H"=>1}, "E"=>{"F"=>1, "A"=>1, "I"=>1}, "F"=>{"E"=>1, "G"=>1, "B"=>1, "J"=>1}, "G"=>{"F"=>1, "H"=>1, "C"=>1, "K"=>1}, "H"=>{"G"=>1, "D"=>1, "L"=>1}, "I"=>{"J"=>1, "E"=>1, "M"=>1}, "J"=>{"I"=>1, "K"=>1, "F"=>1, "N"=>1}, "K"=>{"J"=>1, "L"=>1, "G"=>1, "O"=>1}, "L"=>{"K"=>1, "H"=>1, "P"=>1}, "M"=>{"N"=>1, "I"=>1}, "N"=>{"M"=>1, "O"=>1, "J"=>1}, "O"=>{"N"=>1, "P"=>1, "K"=>1}, "P"=>{"O"=>1, "L"=>1}}
```

Converting the original hash since its format sucks:

```
h.keys.each{|k| h[k] = h[k].keys}
h.default = []
```

The method:

```
def find_path h, src, dst
  paths = [[src]]
  loop do
    paths = paths.flat_map do |path|
      h[path.last].map do |nekst|
        a = [*path, nekst]
        a.last == dst ? (return a) : a
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Trying it:

```
find_path(h, "A", "L")
# => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "H", "L"]
```

Notice that if there is no solution, then the loop may run forever. You might want to limit that by adding a limit to the length.

Comment: I'll give it a try and update the question, too. On what does the number in the hash means and what's the algorithm, etc. Thanks for your time.

Comment: +1 for "Converting the original hash since its format sucks:"